# Требуется создать параметризованную ссылку из формы в Django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

Требуется получить `id(pk)` только что созданного объявления с помощью формы и, с помощью этого, создать параметризованную ссылку для параметризованной html страницы в Django.

Может кто знает из вас как это сделать? Заранее огромное спасибо.

Вот модель (`models.py`):

```py
class Bb(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Tovar')
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Opisanie')
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Cena')
    published = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name='Opublikovano',
    )
    ps = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Po Skriptu')
    rubric = models.ForeignKey(
        'Rubric',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='Rubrika',
    )
```

Вот форма (`forms.py`):

```py
class BbForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bb
        fields = (
            'title', 
            'content', 
            'ps', 
            'price', 
            'rubric',
        )
```

Вот контроллер-класс (`views.py`):

```py
class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
    success_url =
```

`success_url` отсутствует, потому что, мне надо в него передать параметризованную `get` ссылку из `id(pk)` только что созданного объявления.

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) success_url нужен для редиректа после успешного сохранения формы. Объясните подробнее что вы хотите получить в респонсе

Comment: Мне нужно получить id(pk) только что созданного объявления с помощью формы добавления, И, с помощью уже полученного id(pk) из только что созданного объявления, создать параметризованную ссылку, проблема в том, что я не знаю как получить id(pk) именно того объявления, которое я только что создал через форму.

Comment: для каких нужд именно нужна параметризованная ссылка?

Comment: Что бы в итоге, передать параметры в html код 

(Что бы контроллер брал из ссылки id(pk) объявления и, выводил контент ТОЛЬКО этого объявления, а не всех объявлений)

Comment: На сколько я понял, вы пытаетесь переизобрести метод [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: С одной стороны да... Но, этот метод не может получить айди только что созданного объявления из формы (вернее, я не знаю, есть ли у него такая возможность, как я помню, нет), мне нужно получить айди только что созданного объявления из формы, что бы произвести перевод пользователя на параметризованную страницу

Comment: @cauf Может... Можно использовать метод as_view()? Правда, как?...

Comment: Посмотрите уже примеры использования этого метода, в частности под номером 2! Туда передается название view и параметры его вызова. `id` же берется не из формы, а из сохраненного только что объекта объекта в этой же самой функции представления.

Comment: @cauf  Как то я сегодня дико туплю... Даже сейчас, без ЯВНОГО примера, я не совсем понял, если вам не составит труда, можете ли вы мне привести пример прямо как в моём случае? Заранее, огромное спасибо вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно реализовать метод get_absolute_url для модели Bb. success_url в BbCreateView указывать не нужно.
Пример из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse('people.views.details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Вот еще [описание](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) использования такого подхода.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/bb/', BbCreateView.as_view(), name='BbCreateView'),
    ...
]
```

models.py

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Bb(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('BbCreateView', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
```

Comment: Простите, вот так?
`def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('BbCreateView', args=[str(self.id)])

class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
    success_url = get_absolute_url(self)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context`

Comment: Или, мне требуется что то изменить?

Comment: @Mefiseru `success_url = get_absolute_url(self)` вообще уберите с `BbCreateView`. Метод `get_absolute_url` должен быть реализован в модели. Если вы указываете `reverse('BbCreateView', args=[str(self.id)])` то в `urlpatterns` должен быть указан приблизительно такой вот путь - `path('нужный/путь', BbCreateView.as_view(), name='BbCreateView')`

Comment: Как я понял, данный метод достаёт полученные данные из формы и, только что созданной записи, ведь так?

Comment: А, сейчас я понял другую проблему, как указать `html`шаблон методу `get_absolute_url`?

Comment: thanks to your feedback)

Comment: @Mefiseru какой URL вы используете что бы попасть в BbCreateView?

Comment: but, i had another question, how do i can make something like `succes_url` method?

Comment: `path('add/', BbCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),`

Comment: @Mefiseru Ага, я понял :) У вас ведь должна быть еще view для отображения конкретного поста. Если это так то нужно исправить `reverse('название view для отображения конкретного поста', args=[str(self.id)])` и уже в самой view указать template_name.

Comment: А как мне сделать view которая берёт `id(pk)` именно той записи, которую я только что сделал при помощи **контроллера класса**, то есть, формы, разве этот **контроллер класс** не **должен передавать** `id(pk)` только что созданной **записи**? Если это так, то, как мне это реализовать?